# how to disable windows print dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, windows, printing

I need to disable the print dialog for a POS app in exeoutput. direct print to defaut printer.

[image]

Is there any javascript library or software working with php.
I have tried php_printer.dll but my printer in on network and it gives me error
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable printing options in the browser for certain pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359963/how-to-disable-printing-options-in-the-browser-for-certain-pages)

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 1):

> Simply it is not possible, it's because of some reasons:

- the user could want to choose a printer himself
- the user could want to be able to control when his printer gets activated (imagine nasty
  auto-selfprinting advertisement popups)
- the user could want
  to specify printer settings (grayscale or color, resolution, size,
  ...)

> But it is not impossible here are few ways,

- you could use Firefox to achieve this, where you could change the browser setting to enable what they called "Silent Printing", you should set it to "Always" and you'll be good.
- In IE you can use VB script to achieve this.

Source : [javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box), 
[Print a page on local using php (javascript) without Windows print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077832/print-a-page-on-local-using-php-javascript-without-windows-print-dialog-box),

Comment: I am not using browser i am using [exeoutput](http://exeoutput.com/) that create a windows app exe file, so i want to disable windows print dialog.